# Close Graduation Hindering Job Hunt

Tags: interviewing

I am an experienced electronics technician in the USA and 6 months away from graduating with a B.S. in Computer Science.

I'm also not working now and need to find a job quickly. My problem is that if I list that I'm in school, the question of when I'm going to graduate always comes up. While the interviewer thinks my skills and experience are stellar, they also believe that I'm going to bail shortly after I graduate and they understandably don't want to take the time to train somebody who's going to bail.

Getting a software job now will either not pay enough to cover my bills(internships) or will take too long to find (given my lack of experience programming professionally). My family cannot front me any money and nobody wants to offer a reasonable loan to somebody who isn't working.

That leaves me with no choice but to omit my education from my resume and potentially lie if pressed about my educational goals. Given the constraints I just described, what strategy would you all recommend for seeking employment? I would rather not be misleading in interviews, but at the same time I have to pay rent and put food on the table -- fast.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: What time are your courses? If they are during the day, aren't you expecting flexibility from the employer anyway?

Comment: **Voted to close as unclear as we need more information.** @OP: What do you want to do? Find a job for 6 months? Find permanent employment while you're still studying? Do you want to start working while you're still studying?

Answer (score 10):

In this situation I would look for temporary work, not try and get a full time job I have no intention of staying in. It really depends how fussy you are.

I cleaned offices at night while studying during the day as an adult, and made a surprising amount of money doing it, but some people would think that's beneath them. I also mowed the odd lawn, moved furniture, and pretty much anything else someone would pay me for. When you need food on the table and bills paid anything like that is worth a look.

Universities often have job boards and advice that are worth looking into when you run out of food (or beer) money.

Comment: You can can also look specifically for short-term contracts. Replace someone on maternity leave or work a small project that lasts only 6 months etc. Go through a temp agency. Freelancing is a possibility too since you are in the software field in school.

Comment: @HLGEM freelancing as an electronics technician might be viable, unsure what that is though, there's always work for a registered electrician, but this sounds different.